# How to add CIDFont like font name contains Chinese characters？

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

There are many different fonts in my Pdf files,like 方正细等线简体,方正黑体_GBK,etc.So when I use a command `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSTOPONERROR -dNOOUTERSAVE -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dCompressFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=false -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -dCompatibilityLevel=1.6 -sOutputFile=output.pdf 1000027661706311repair1.pdf` convert pdf to other format,it run and report an error:

```
Processing pages 1 through 3.
Page 1
Can't find CID font "方正黑体_GBK".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /方正黑体_GBK, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-GB1" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-GB1 ... Done.
Can't find CID font "方正细等线简体".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /方正细等线简体, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find CID font "楷体_GB2312".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /楷体_GB2312, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 9497580 8102504 3768888 2094014 3 done.
Page 2
Can't find CID font "方正黑体_GBK".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /方正黑体_GBK, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-GB1 ... Done.
Can't find CID font "方正细等线简体".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /方正细等线简体, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Page 3
Can't find CID font "方正细等线简体".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /方正细等线简体, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-GB1 ... Done.
Can't find CID font "方正黑体_GBK".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /方正黑体_GBK, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Can't find CID font "楷体_GB2312".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-GB1 for /楷体_GB2312, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
```

this is my /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/Resource/CIDFSubet folder:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23M 12月 12 09:17 DroidSansFallback.ttf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  35 12月 11 10:19 FZBSK.TTF -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/FZBSK.TTF
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 12月 11 10:19 FZDBSK.TTF -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/FZDBSK.TTF
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  35 12月 11 10:19 FZHTK.TTF -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/FZHTK.TTF
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  35 12月 11 10:19 FZSSK.TTF -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/FZSSK.TTF
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 12月 11 10:19 FZXBSK.TTF -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/FZXBSK.TTF
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  37 12月 11 10:17 FZXDXJW.TTF -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/FZXDXJW.TTF
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  42 12月 11 10:19 KaiTi_GB2312.ttf -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/KaiTi_GB2312.ttf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 12月 11 10:19 msyhbd.ttc -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/msyhbd.ttc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  35 12月 11 10:19 msyhl.ttc -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/msyhl.ttc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  34 12月 11 10:19 msyh.ttc -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/msyh.ttc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  37 12月 11 10:19 simfang.ttf -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/simfang.ttf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 12月 11 10:19 simhei.ttf -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/simhei.ttf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 12月 11 10:19 simkai.ttf -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/simkai.ttf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 12月 11 10:19 simsun.ttc -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/simsun.ttc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 12月 11 10:19 simyou.ttf -> /usr/share/fonts/winfonts/SIMYOU.TTF
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  42 12月 11 10:19 wqy-zenhei.ttc -> /usr/share/fonts/wqy-zenhei/wqy-zenhei.ttc
```

this is my /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.50/Resource/Init/cidfmap.local

```
...
/MicrosoftYaHei << /FileType /TrueType
  /Path pssystemparams /GenericResourceDir get
  (CIDFSubst/msyh.ttc) concatstrings
  /SubfontID 0
  /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;
/MicrosoftYaHei-Bold << /FileType /TrueType
  /Path pssystemparams /GenericResourceDir get
  (CIDFSubst/msyhbd.ttc) concatstrings
  /SubfontID 0
  /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;
/MicrosoftYaHeiLight << /FileType /TrueType
  /Path pssystemparams /GenericResourceDir get
  (CIDFSubst/msyhl.ttc) concatstrings
  /SubfontID 0
  /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;
/NSimSun << /FileType /TrueType
  /Path pssystemparams /GenericResourceDir get
  (CIDFSubst/simsun.ttc) concatstrings
  /SubfontID 1
  /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;
/SimHei << /FileType /TrueType
  /Path pssystemparams /GenericResourceDir get
  (CIDFSubst/simhei.ttf) concatstrings
  /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;
/SimSun << /FileType /TrueType
  /Path pssystemparams /GenericResourceDir get
  (CIDFSubst/simsun.ttc) concatstrings
  /SubfontID 0
  /CSI [(GB1) 5] >> ;
...
```

I know this pdf need some fonts with Chinese characters,but ghostscript's config files are ascii text,it does not support wrinting into Chinese...
I noticed some interesting thing when get pdf's metadata using iText,the Chinese fonts name becomes the following format：

```
fontTemp = /#bf#ac#cc#e5_GB2312
fontTemp = /#b7#bd#d5#fd#ba#da#cc#e5_GBK
fontTemp = /#b7#bd#d5#fd#cf#b8#b5#c8#cf#df#bc#f2#cc#e5
fontTemp = /STSong-Light
```

Does anyone know how to add CIDFont with Chinese characters?

Answer (score 0):

The PDF/A specification requires that all fonts be embedded (in fact all CIDFonts are supposed to be embedded in PDF files anwyay). You do not appear to have supplied the missing CIDFont to Ghostscript at all or, if you have added it to the Ghostscript list of fonts, you have not stated what you did to add it.

You need to create a cidfmap file (you can use the one in ghostpdl/Resource/Init) and include the directory containing it using the -I switch. The easiest solution is to modify the one in ghostpdl/Resource/Init and add -I/ghostpdl/Resource/Init to the command line.

Obviously the entry you add will need to get the filename of the missing font file correct. You will almost certainly have to use PostScript to create the name as well, because you'll have to use binary data, potentially including 0x20 or 0x00 character codes.

Something like :

```
<B9656B63C67E497BBF7E807B534F> cvn << ....>> ;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I saw this expression in Use.htm 8.4 yesterda [link](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/Use.htm#yCIDFontSubstitution). I know ＭＳゴシック becomes  #82l#82r#83S#83V#83b#83N and  finally 82C68272835383568362834E，but I dont know the conversion process between and among .I couldn't find the relevant information about it...

Comment: There is no 'conversion process', the font name in cidfmap needs to be the same as the name of the font in the PDF file. That name can be encoded as Unicode, Shift-JIS, whatever, it doesn't matter. All that matters is that the font name of the CIDFont in the PDF file matches the font name in cidfmap. FWIW the # syntax is for a string using hex for the character codes, and the same data without the # is for a hex string (enclosed in <>).